# How to encrypt the entire PostgreSQL database in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

So we have this PostgreSQL managed by Heroku and I am looking for a way to encrypt the entire database. I already searched for it online but the only thing I found was the PGCrypto extension.

The problem with PGCrypto is that we need to change the database structure and field types in order to support it and in addition, we also have to change our Python backend code in order to decrypt the values before sending them to our client. And I also think we won't be able to use the existing rows anymore as they are unencrypted so decryption won't work.

I have also read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/encrypting-heroku-postgres-with-your-key , but it requires the "Private Shield" tier.

Is there a more elegant solution for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One options is to use a database gateway to perform the encryption. (Full disclosure: I'm the founder of JumpWire).

A database gateway will sit between your application and the database and selectively encrypt/decrypt individual columns, based on configuration. The advantages of using a separate service is that it doesn't require you to make changes to your application or move data out of your database, while significantly upgrading the level of security around your data.

A couple of gateways to consider are Acra (https://github.com/cossacklabs/acra) and my company JumpWire (https://github.com/extragoodlabs/jumpwire)